# Android: Stretch bitmap to fill entire screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a bitmap as a background for activity. The code of the custom background is:

```
<item>
<bitmap android:src="@drawable/fog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             />
</item>
```

However it sits in the middle and doesn't occupy the entire screen space.
How can I make it fill all the available space?
I tried setting width and height to fill_parent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: it worked, but the aspect ratio is distorted. Is there any option to stretch but not change the aspect ratio?

Comment: Just set one of the layout_width to match_parent..(whichever looks better) that wouldn't fill up the screen but it will be largest image on maximum part of screen without messing up the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the @androidz post. To avoid distortion, you can use the setAdjustViewBounds function (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds%28boolean%29)).

Comment: i added 'setAdjustViewBounds', still there is apparent stretching.

Comment: It will work if you experiment with the different parameters, and set the property before you use setImageBitmap();

Comment: i'm using it as a custom background xml file.
It contains the background color as well as a translucent image over it.

Comment: You might be able to set this property in the xml. Check out the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

android:scaleType="fitXY" is what i use to fill imageviews, i never had bitmap as item, theres cropping ones too